# Multiply SQL where

Tags: sql, replace, phpmyadmin, where-clause

I have merged some clients from one SQL to another (209 clients) using a code like this listed:

```
    INSERT INTO `tblclients` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `companyname`, `email`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `postcode`, `country`, `phonenumber`, `password`, `currency`, `defaultgateway`, `credit`, `taxexempt`, `latefeeoveride`, `overideduenotices`, `separateinvoices`, `disableautocc`, `datecreated`, `notes`, `billingcid`, `securityqid`, `securityqans`, `groupid`, `cardtype`, `cardlastfour`, `cardnum`, `startdate`, `expdate`, `issuenumber`, `bankname`, `banktype`, `bankcode`, `bankacct`, `gatewayid`, `lastlogin`, `ip`, `host`, `status`, `language`, `pwresetkey`, `pwresetexpiry`) VALUES
('Name', 'LastName', 'companyname', 'gdfgdfg@example.no', 'Gatenavn 6', '', 'Halden', 'Østfold', '1780', 'NO', '+4452335445', '339bfb3999994f0e7c696c7cafafbbe:U#!!I', 1, '', '0.00', 'on', 'on', 'on', '', '', '2011-05-11', '', 0, 0, 'YAiAIpIrK5KcghdhdfgdfFGDF/jWZd7654564A==', 1, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2011-12-31 01:20:43', '81.000.00.000', '81.000.00.000', 'Active', '', '', 0),
('Name2', 'LastName', 'companyname', 'gdfgdfg@example.no', 'Nilsen 154', '', 'Fredrikstad', 'Østfold', '1904', 'NO', '+445244535445', '339bfb36654f0e7c696c7cafafbbe:U#!!I', 1, '', '0.00', 'on', 'on', 'on', '', '', '2011-05-11', '', 0, 0, 'YAiAIpIrK5KcghdhdfgdfFG56465DF/jWZd7A==', 2, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2011-12-31 01:20:43', '81.000.00.000', '81.000.00.000', 'Active', '', '', 0),
('Cliff', 'LastName', 'companyname', 'gdfgdfg@example.no', 'Josefineveri 2', '', 'Oslo', 'Østfold', '4544', 'NO', '+445244, '339bfb35556330e7c696c7cafafbbe:U#!!I', 1, '', '0.00', 'on', 'on', 'on', '', '', '2011-05-11', '', 0, 0, 'YAiAIpIrK5KcghdhdfgdfFGDF/jWZd74546A==', 3, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2011-12-31 01:20:43', '81.000.00.000', '81.000.00.000', 'Active', '', '', 0),
('Ann', 'LastName', 'companyname', 'gdfgdfg@example.no', 'oskar 183', '', 'Hamar', 'Østfold', '0001', '5158', '+44524445445', '339bfb6644f0e7c696c7cafafbbe:U#!!I', 1, '', '0.00', 'on', 'on', 'on', '', '', '2011-05-11', '', 0, 0, 'YAiAIpIrK5KcghdhdfgdfFGDF/jWZd755A==', 2, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2011-12-31 01:20:43', '81.000.00.000', '81.000.00.000', 'Active', '', '', 0),
```

How can I change `groupid` to 5 on all clents that is listed, but not them that is not listed? I have like 500 clients from before that not should get new `groupid`.
The clients are imported, so maybe I can use the SQL WHERE or something to do it?

**Solution**: I know the latest ID that was BEFORE the import. So I just did:

```
 UPDATE `norskhos_nhnfm`.`tblclients`
 SET `groupip` = '5'
 WHERE `tblclients`.`id` >= 571;
```

Comment: that's a table ? I think you should modify your design..

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by "change groupid to 5 on all clents that is listed, but not them that is not listed?"

If I understand correctly...in SQL Server (which I believe you are not using, but similar) I would do:

assuming the email is unique

```
UPDATE `norskhos_nhnfm`.`tblclients`
 SET `groupip` = '5'
 WHERE `tblclients`.`id` >= 571;
 AND email not in(not them that is not listed)
```